# Substituting javascript variables inside Django template tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I have the following `success function` of an ajax call which creates the HTML for an image and appends it to a `div`.

```
success:function(response)
    {
        var new_comment = $('<div class="row" style="background-color:white;margin:5px;">{% thumbnail '+response.author_image+' "35x35" crop="center" as im %}<img src = "{{im.url}}" width="{{im.width}}" height="{{im.height}}" >{% endthumbnail %}')

        $(".comments").append( new_comment );

    },
```

Im using [sorl-thumbnail](https://github.com/mariocesar/sorl-thumbnail) app for displaying images in template. And this is done by the `{% thumbnail url ...%}` tag that requires a url for the image.

This url is stored in  `response.author_image` and Im trying to substitute this value inside the template tag.

`response.author_image` holds this value `'/media/Images/Profile_2_(PSF)_5.png'`

Doing this by

```
{% thumbnail '+reponse.author_image'+ ... %}
```

is substituting the variable name instead of its value:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/hammad/virt_env/virt1/gccFishing/gccFishing/media/+response.author_image+'
```

How can I substitute the value of `response.author_image` inside the `thumbnail template tag`?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it's pretty clear that you don't understand the difference between the server-side template language and the client-side Javascript, which is a pretty fundamental thing not to understand.

The template tags are evaluated on the server side, and all the Javascript will ever see is the rendered response of those tags. That means there is no way to insert the result of a JS function into the tag itself.

But since you are using an Ajax call anyway, why don't you return the full HTML of the div - including the rendered template tag - from that response? That is, use a template fragment and render that as the response of the Ajax view.

Answer (score 0):

There is an important distinction between Django template code and in-browser JavaScript that you seem to be missing:

*Django templates are build on the server side, while JavaScript is executed on the client side.*

That means that template code is always executed *before* JavaScript (as it is executed by the server, before the page is sent to the client). As a consequence it is absolutely impossible to manipulate Django template code using JavaScript.

One option is to use `sorl-thumbnail`'s `get_thumbnail` method to get the proper thumbnail's url on the server side, and then to return it in your AJAX response, instead of `author_image`.